# Why BinaryReader.ReadInt64() read data as upper/lower separately?

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I have questions for BinaryReader by Microsoft.

From https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs ,

```
public virtual long ReadInt64() {
        FillBuffer(8);
        uint lo = (uint)(m_buffer[0] | m_buffer[1] << 8 |
                         m_buffer[2] << 16 | m_buffer[3] << 24);
        uint hi = (uint)(m_buffer[4] | m_buffer[5] << 8 |
                         m_buffer[6] << 16 | m_buffer[7] << 24);
        return (long) ((ulong)hi) << 32 | lo;
}
```

It parse data as two parts (upper 32bit, lower 32bit) for Int64 data. But I think that it is rebundant. So the method like below also should work.

```
public virtual long ReadInt64Other() {
        FillBuffer(8);
        return (long)m_buffer[0] | 
               (long)m_buffer[1] << 8 |
               (long)m_buffer[2] << 16 |
               (long)m_buffer[3] << 24 |
               (long)m_buffer[4] << 32 |
               (long)m_buffer[5] << 40 |
               (long)m_buffer[6] << 48 |
               (long)m_buffer[7] << 56;
}
```

Is there any reason for Microsoft use upper/lower style parsing?

Comment: Maybe for readability.

Comment: Because who ever wrote it liked it that way, also they might not have like 40, 48, 56,  and its also consistent with int32. Anyway there is no diffrence

Comment: Its not *parsing*. It's just bit-twiddling. But it may be that the first form gets better assembly if it's being compiled for 32-bit architectures where it cannot assume access to 64-bit registers.

Comment: As written by Damien... And when the .NET was born, 32 bits machines where much more common than 64 bits

Comment: There is no parsing and no (separate) reading here. Just the combining of two  Int32 values (from four bytes), and the style is probably for being clear about little/big endian.

Comment: I think that what @bommelding says is the answer. It is for little/big endian awareness.